# How Do You SELECT Both With and Without a WHERE in a Query?

Tags: sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a single table, *my_table*, with data like the following:

```
+---------------------------+
|Accesses | Fruit   | Level |
+---------------------------+
|      5  | Apple   |     2 |
|      2  | Banana  |     3 |
|      2  | Apple   |     1 |
|      6  | Cherry  |     4 |
|     12  | Apple   |     4 |
|      9  | Banana  |     1 |
|      1  | Durian  |     2 |
+---------------------------+
```

I'm trying to write a query that would both sum the number of accesses GROUP BY'd fruit and the total number of access for each fruit, but only the accesses for levels less than 4. A result for that query would be:

```
+---------------------------|-------------- +
|Fruit   | FilteredAccesses | TotalAccesses |
+---------------------------+---------------+
|Apple   |                7 |            19 | 
|Banana  |               11 |            11 |
|Durian  |                1 |             1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I tried the following self join, but didn't get the expected results:

```
SELECT A.Fruit, SUM(A.Accesses) AS FilteredAccesses, SUM(B.Accesses) As TotalAccesses
FROM my_table A, my_table B
WHERE (A.Fruit = B.Fruit) AND (A.Level < 4)
GROUP BY A.Fruit
```

Is there something that I'm missing? Could this even be done with a self join?

Comment: Why is 'cherry' excluded from the results?

Comment: Because I'm interested in entries where the level is < 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT A.Fruit, SUM(CASE WHEN A.LEVEL < 4 THEN A.Accesses ELSE 0 END) AS FilteredAccesses,
      SUM(A.Accesses) As TotalAccesses
FROM my_table A
GROUP BY A.Fruit
```

Comment: So in this case, rows that `A.Level < 4` doesn't satisfy will still be included in the results? I guess I could `ORDER BY A.Fruit DESC`.

Comment: You can use a `having` filter on the end of the query:
`having SUM(CASE WHEN A.LEVEL < 4 THEN A.Accesses ELSE 0 END) > 0`

Comment: @AndrewSayer Looks like this results in a syntax error:

`SELECT A.Fruit, HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN A.LEVEL < 4 THEN A.Accesses ELSE 0 END) > 0 AS FilteredAccesses,
      SUM(A.Accesses) As TotalAccesses
FROM my_table A
GROUP BY A.Fruit`

Did I miss something?

Comment: You missed the " on the end of the query". `SELECT A.Fruit, SUM(CASE WHEN A.LEVEL < 4 THEN A.Accesses ELSE 0 END) AS FilteredAccesses,
      SUM(A.Accesses) As TotalAccesses
FROM my_table A
GROUP BY A.Fruit having SUM(CASE WHEN A.LEVEL < 4 THEN A.Accesses ELSE 0 END) > 0`

Answer (score 2):

No need for a self join. You can do this in a single aggregation query. The trick is to use a `case` expression on `level` to compute the "filtered" accesses, so that only rows that satisfy the conditions are taken into account.

```
select fruit,
    sum(case when level < 4 then accesses else 0 end) filtered_accesses,
    sum(accesses) total_accesses
from mytable
group by fruit
```

This technique is called *conditional aggregation*.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to not include the rows that don't meet the `Level < 4` condition? Otherwise, they're included from what I see.

Comment: @HerbPowell: they are included in the `total_accesses`, but not in the `filtered_accesses` - which is how I understood your question.